# Outlook doesn't resolve names from EML

Tags: outlook, eml

I'm currently building an EML file and have my web application send it to the user's Outlook.

The issue is that it doesn't resolve the names specified in the TO/CC accordingly (ex. John Doe). Users have to manually edit all the names for them to work.

Noting that if the same name not resolved through the EML was to be typed manually, it would resolve without any problems. If names are specified as emails, those work as expected too.

Is there a way to improve how Outlook resolves names when using an EML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open an unsent EML file in Outlook and hit Ctrl+K, it will attempt to resolve the names.Other than that, there is no magic - if you cannot provide an SMTP address when you build the EML file on a server, Outlook will try to resolve the name only if the user explicitly asks to do that.

To show the message as unsent (draft), you need to include `X-Unsent: 1` MIME header .

Comment: I've tried this, but it still doesn't resolve. Strangely, if I type manually the same name that doesn't resolve, at the end of the TO field for example, it resolves fine.

Comment: What does "doesn't resolve" mean? Nothing happens? Or you get an error? Does Outlook show your message as draft (editable)? You need to make sure you include the `X-Unsent: 1` MIME header for that.

Comment: it states: "We won't be able to deliver this message to x recipients because their email addresses are no longer valid". If I manually input them immediately after loading the email, they'll resolve fine. Example: Joe Smith in TO field from EML when opened will be part of the error. Put him manually after opening, it'll be fine. I already have the header you mention in the markup of the EML.

Comment: So what happen if you place the cursor in the To edit box and hit Ctrl+K to force Outlook to resolve the names?

Comment: Alternatively, you can avoid populating the To/CC/BCC headers if you don't have the email address. This way the user will be forced to manually add a recipient.

Comment: Ctrl+K does nothing. Been testing a bit more and specifying an email resolves automatically when the EML loads. Also, specifying name <email> works too. Tried only last name, first name, which doesn't work either. Seems adding the email, in this scenario is key.

Comment: So you do have the email address? Then it sounds like you are not formatting the To/CC headers correctly. Format them as `"recipient name" <address@domain.demo>`

Comment: No emails to work with. We might just have to use emails instead of names and refactor our processes.

Comment: That would be a much better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

EML files don't provide anything (any instructions) for forcing Outlook to resolve names specified in the TO/CC accordingly.